# Reverse Engineering Go obfuscated binaries

Tags: windows, binary-analysis, obfuscation, shellcode, go

I have been trying to understand the working of this go malware by reversing it, which can be found [here](https://github.com/optiv/Freeze) , so basically this stuff takes a shellcode as an input, and converts it to an exe or dll file, turns out the exe generated is a go file which obfuscates most of the functions using garble[which is a code obfuscator written in go], so the main challenge over here is to understand or look for the subroutine, which is either encoding/obfuscating the function names and other identifiers with base64 encoding, one of the challenge garble presents is the obfuscator **hooks directly into 'go build' via its -toolexec flag** . I am attaching the link to binary along with some of the screenshots which can bring more context to my current problem, in case I missed something, my apologies.

Link to binary : https://easyupload.io/xcqeod

Screenshots :

[image: Garble obfuscated malware]
[image: functions]
[image: functions]

Answer (score 0):

Unable to restore function names because they were obscured (renamed with trash names) at source level. I believe most of these functions are trash dummy functions without any useful logic.
To understand the activity of this binary is to run in any sandbox with logging.